# Javascript - Reduce the number of IF statements

Tags: javascript

is there a javascript select case type function to set a variable how the following code would perform? i see a CASE function but it doesn't really seem that much more efficient from a line number footprint

```
  if (i == 1){
    ResToUse = Res1
  }

  if (i == 2){
    ResToUse = Res2
  }

  if (i == 3){
    ResToUse = Res3
  }

  if (i == 4){
    ResToUse = Res4
  }

  if (i == 5){
    ResToUse = Res5
  }

  if (i == 6){
    ResToUse = Res6
  }

  if (i == 7){
    ResToUse = Res7
  }

  if (i == 8){
    ResToUse = Res8
  }

  if (i == 9){
    ResToUse = Res9
  }

  if (i == 10){
    ResToUse = Res10
  }

  if (i == 11){
    ResToUse = Res11
  }

  if (i == 12){
    ResToUse = Res12
  }
```

Comment: Make an array of res and then use the index as index in array. And in the end, you could do an `res[i] || defaultValue`

Comment: There's a lot of different solutions to this kind of problem, typically some form of lookup table (object, array, etc.).  Some of how you'd design this depends on exactly what you're trying to accomplish - this could be as simple as an array or as complex as a dependency injection system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array. Like this:

```
var resArray = [Res1, Res2,...];
ResToUse = resArray[i - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `window` object:

```
ResToUse = window['Res'+1];
```

Comment: While this is probably going to work in most cases I would avoid it as the scope can be different. An array will be a better option.

Comment: OP is looking for writing lesser code, what makes you think that creating array will need less code as compared to my post?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope of your objects you could just do `ResToUse = window['Res'+i]`